# If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\cdot(x-x_{0})^n$ converges for $x \in (x_{0}-r, x_{0} + r]$

Tags: calculus

Prove that If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\cdot(x-x_{0})^n$ converges for $x \in (x_{0}-r, x_{0} + r]$, then it conditionally converges for $x = x_{0} + r$

$r$ here is the radius of converges for that power series. I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n\cdot r^n$ converges, but why does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lvert c_n\cdot r^n \rvert$ diverge?

Comment: What would absolute converge at $x_0+r$ imply at $x_0-r?$

Comment: That $x_0 - r$ is within the convergence interval which is a contradiction?